# duplicate values in string: need help with the logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

The datatable "dtTypeId" in the folowing code returns 2 columns Type names and IDs as :-

```
TypeId TypeName
1      Type1  
2      Type2
3      Type3
```

The problem is that in th combo box, there are only 2 items that are check marked ie "Type1" and "Type2" but in the Text of Radcombobox it is displaying the text

as:-

Type1,Type1,Type1,Type1,Type2,Type2,Type2,Type2.
I want the text of the combo box as Type1,Type2(ONLy those that are check marked). Why those duplicate values?

What is wrong with the logic below? please help..thanks..

```
foreach (RadComboBoxItem item1 in radComboBoxTypes.Items)
                {

                    Label lblTypeId = item1.FindControl("lblTypeId") as Label;
                    CheckBox chkType = item1.FindControl("chkType") as CheckBox;
                    Label lblTypeNames = item1.FindControl("lblTypeNames") as Label;
                    bllMyClass objMyClass = new bllMyClass();
                    objMyClass.TextID = int.Parse(lblTextID.Text);
                    DataTable dtTypeId = new DataTable();
                    dtTypeId = objMyClass.GetTypesByTextID();
                    if (dtTypeId.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {

                        foreach (RadComboBoxItem item2 in radComboBoxTypes.Items)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < dtTypeId.Rows.Count; i++)
                            {
                                if (lblTypeId.Text == dtTypeId.Rows[i]["TypeId"].ToString())
                                {
                                    chkType.Checked = true;
                                    checkedTextType += lblTypeNames.Text + ", ";
                                }
                            }

                            if (chkType.Checked == true)
                            {

                                checkedTextType += lblTypeNames.Text + ", ";

                            }
                            radComboBoxTypes.Text = checkedTextType;
                        }

                    }

                }
```

**@Bolu : I followed your approach but its not working correctly..It is now displaying the text in the combobox as type1type1, , type1type1, , type1type1, , type1type1, , type2type2, , type2type2, , type2type2, , type2type2,**

@bOLU
its giving an error on this line...checkedTextType += checkedTextType==string.Empty?lblTypeNames.Text：", " + lblTypeNames.Text ; it says "Unexpected character '：'"

Comment: @Bolu :: I have tried that and modified the code too..just not getting the spark :(

Answer (score 1):

With a quick look of your code I can see following problems: you need to update those label/checkbox values in your inner foreach loop, or just break out when you find the first match

```
foreach (RadComboBoxItem item1 in radComboBoxTypes.Items)//for item1
{
      Label lblTypeId = item1.FindControl("lblTypeId") as Label; //lblTypeId.Text=="1"
      Label lblTypeNames = item1.FindControl("lblTypeNames") as Label; //lblTypeNames.Text=="Type1"
      .....
      foreach (RadComboBoxItem item2 in radComboBoxTypes.Items)//item1 || <item2>
      {
             for (int i = 0; i < dtTypeId.Rows.Count; i++)
             {
                  if (lblTypeId.Text == dtTypeId.Rows[i]["TypeId"].ToString())//true || <true>
                  {
                      chkType.Checked = true;
                      checkedTextType += lblTypeNames.Text + ", ";//checkedTextType=="Type1" || <checkedTextType=="Type1, Type1, Type1">
                  }
              }

              if (chkType.Checked == true)//true || true
              {
                   checkedTextType += lblTypeNames.Text + ", "; //checkedTextType =="Type1, Type1" || <checkedTextType =="Type1, Type1, Type1, Type1">
              }

       }
}

//Then when out loop goes to item2, you will have "Type2, Type2, Type2, Type2" added to your checkedTextType
```

Again, the problem can be easily identified by using debug.

**EDIT: what you should do:**

```
  //pseudo code
    foreach (RadComboBoxItem item1 in radComboBoxTypes.Items)
    {
              Label lblTypeId = item1.FindControl("lblTypeId") as Label;
              CheckBox chkType = item1.FindControl("chkType") as CheckBox;
              Label lblTypeNames = item1.FindControl("lblTypeNames") as Label;
              bllMyClass objMyClass = new bllMyClass();
              objMyClass.TextID = int.Parse(lblTextID.Text);
              DataTable dtTypeId = new DataTable();
              dtTypeId = objMyClass.GetTypesByTextID();
              for (int i = 0; i < dtTypeId.Rows.Count; i++)
              {
                    if (lblTypeId.Text == dtTypeId.Rows[i]["TypeId"].ToString())
                    {
                       chkType.Checked = true;
                       checkedTextType += checkedTextType==string.Empty?lblTypeNames.Text:", " + lblTypeNames.Text ; 
                       break;                                 
                    }
              } 
     }
     radComboBoxTypes.Text = checkedTextType;
```

Comment: I followed your approach but its not working correctly..It is now displaying the text in the combobox as type1type1, , type1type1, , type1type1, , type1type1, , type2type2, , type2type2, , type2type2, , type2type2,

Comment: You need to replace all your code with my code above, so you should have only 1 `foreach` loop.  Also check your `GetTypesByTextID()` function, it should return only 1 record?

Comment: its giving an error on this line...checkedTextType += checkedTextType==string.Empty?lblTypeNames.Text：", " + lblTypeNames.Text ;  it says "Unexpected character '：'"

Comment: GetTypesByTextID() returns a datatable with values as Type1, Type2 ie a datatable with these 2 values and their IDs

Comment: Hi, in this case just add a `break`; and for the error just replace `：` with `:` by retyping it (it looks the same but they are different).. Or you can just re-copy my code above to replace yours.